# How can I subclass a Minion command with getopt?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

One of the tasks in a [Minion](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Minion) job queue I am using needs user and password.

I found a good description on how to pass parameters to a Mojo app [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390960/how-can-i-take-credentials-from-the-command-line-in-a-mojolicious-app) so I went about it like this:

```
package Minion::Command::minion::secure_worker;

use Mojo::Base 'Minion::Command::minion::worker';
use Mojo::Util 'getopt';

sub run {
    my ( $self, @args ) = @_;

    my $worker = $self->app->minion->worker;
    my $status = $worker->status;

    getopt \@args,
    'U|username=s' => \my $username,
    'P|password=s' => \my $password;

    $self->app->credentials->{username} = $username;
    $self->app->credentials->{password} = $password;

    return $self->SUPER::run;
}

1
```

However when I try to pass options that were in the original worker command - such as `-j` I get:

```
Unknown option: j
```

Why is that? It looks like subclassing a command doesn't work, or that getopt slurps everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls to `getopt` are not composable. You can try to handle (and then pass on) all options that your superclass handles as well, or call [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) yourself with the `pass_through` option. This will ignore all unknown options:

```
package Minion::Command::minion::secure_worker;

use Mojo::Base 'Minion::Command::minion::worker';
use Getopt::Long 'GetOptionsFromArray';
use Getopt::Long ':config', 'pass_through';

sub run {
    my ( $self, @args ) = @_;

    my $worker = $self->app->minion->worker;
    my $status = $worker->status;

    GetOptionsFromArray \@args,
    'U|username=s' => \my $username,
    'P|password=s' => \my $password;

    $self->app->credentials->{username} = $username;
    $self->app->credentials->{password} = $password;

    return $self->SUPER::run;
}

1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: You can do this in the getopt function from Mojo::Util (it's just a wrapper): `getopt \@args, ['pass_through'], ...;`